# comparing historical data in same table

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare Historical data of two columns i,e I want to compare this year's data with the previous year's data.I did an Inner join on same table

```
select
    a.dt,a.brand,
    a.total_fans,
    a.fan_growth,
    b.total_fans as total_fans_BOY,
    b.fan_growth as Fan_Growth_BOY,
    b.Before_One_Year INTO TM_DATA_BOY
from
    TEMP_TM_DATA a
    LEFT JOIN TEMP_TM_DATA b
        on a.dt = b.Before_One_Year
            and a.brand = b.brand
            and a.source = b.source
```

(BOY= Before one year)

Data is in table TEMP_TM_DATA, I created a column called `Before_One_Year` in `TEMP_TM_DATA` using `DATEADD(Year,-1,dt)` and then used above query.

```
The table structure is like this 


+----------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| Present Date   |No of fans  | NO Of fans BOY |Before One year(date)|
+----------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 28-Jan-2014    | 30         |             24 |28-Jan-2013          |
| 1-Feb-2014     | 35         |             30 |1-Feb-2013           |
+-------+--------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

The result set is not being displayed like the above one, instead it is being displayed like this

```
+----------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| Present Date   |No of fans  | NO Of fans BOY |Before One year(date)|
+----------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 28-Jan-2014    | 30         |             24 |*28-Jan-2014*        |
| 1-Feb-2014     | 35         |             30 |*1-Feb-2014*         |
+-------+--------+------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server. Pick one

Comment: @user1841772 edit your question and update the table structure... Do not put it in comments...

Comment: Did you get the result? If any issue, describe it clearly...

Comment: In the `JOIN` condition you have `a.dt = b.Before_One_Year` so the two values are equal by definition, also the structure of the `SELECT` is different from the table structure displayed, how is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this query

```
select a.dt, a.brand, a.total_fans, a.fan_growth, b.total_fans as total_fans_BOY, b.fan_growth as Fan_Growth_BOY, a.Before_One_Year INTO TM_DATA_BOY from TEMP_TM_DATA a LEFT JOIN TEMP_TM_DATA b on a.Before_One_Year=b.dt and a.brand=b.brand and a.source=b.source
```

this fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.dt,
        a.brand,
        a.total_fans,
        a.fan_growth,
        b.total_fans AS Total_Fans_BOY,
        b.fan_growth as Fan_Growth_BOY,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, a.dt), 106) AS Before_One_Year
INTO    TM_DATA_BOY
FROM    TEMP_TM_DATA AS a LEFT JOIN 
        TEMP_TM_DATA AS b 
            ON a.brand = b.brand AND
               a.source = b.source AND
               CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.dt, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, a.dt), 101)
```

Comment: don't you think 
`CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.dt, 101)= CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, a.dt), 101)`
should be the last line.

Comment: Did you try and get the answer?

Comment: I used this query
'
select 
a.dt,
a.brand,
a.total_fans,
a.fan_growth,
b.total_fans as total_fans_BOY,
b.fan_growth as Fan_Growth_BOY,
a.Before_One_Year 
INTO 
TM_DATA_BOY 
from 
TEMP_TM_DATA a 
LEFT JOIN TEMP_TM_DATA b 
on
a.Before_One_Year=b.dt and a.brand=b.brand and a.source=b.source
`
this fixed everything

Comment: Good! Just FYI, whenever you fixed something, put your comments, and your answers too... It will be helpful to others.